# MongoDB update only changed fields in an object instead of replacing the whole object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update a document contains object in MongoDB.
Since the updated object is given from the user, I don't know what exactly he was about to change.

For example I have this document in users collection:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  date: new Date(),
  info: {
    first_name: "a",
    last_name: "b",
    phone: "c"
  }
}
```

The user is able to edit first_name and last_name but not phone.

This is the `req.body` (the input I receive from the user):

```
{
  info: {
    first_name: "aa"
  }
}
```

Now in order to update only "info.first_name" and preserve the other fields that are stored in the info ojbect, I have to set an update query like this:

```
db.users.update({}, {$set: {"info.first_name": req.body.info.first_name}}, cb);
```

But the input is can be dynamic and changeable. 
I don't know if it's always be first name that was updated it can be last name or even other sub object like address: "info.address.city" (for example)

For that reason I handle those updates like this:

```
$set: req.body
```

And that is it. It works but I have an issue with this.
It replaces the whole info ojbect and doesn't preserve other keys that were stored in it - phone is getting deleted and last name is getting deleted.

Is there a way to tell MongoDB to not replace the whole object but just update those keys that are mentioned?

Comment: For anyone looking into this now, especially if you want one request with upsert, I recommend looking into updating with aggregation pipelines: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 4):

would it not be easier to read the current entry in the DB and spread the req.body over the current entry?

```
// read current entry in database
let currentObject = await user.findOne({_id});

// merge current entry with changed updated key:values
let newObject = ( currentObject, ...req.body );

// write update to database
let user.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, {$set: newObject}, )
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers

Comment: It would be easier, but primarily - atomic, to be able to do it in one db operation.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked into it, and you can't set mongo to only update specific fields. What you can do instead is dynamically build your query based on input.

I usually looped through the input, and then validated what was allowed to be modified, and built a dynamic query based on that:

```
var updateQuery = {};
for(key of req.body.info) {
    if (req.body.info.hasOwnProperty(key) && canBeModified(key)) //this would be a function to validate what can be updated
        updateQuery['info.' + key] = req.body.info[key]};
}
db.users.update({}, {$set: updateQuery}, cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$or` and `$ne`, you can indeed create one update operation that:

- compares fields
- only modifies the changed fields
- doesn't do anything if nothing changed

Here's the basic idea:

```
const new_info = {
    first_name: "aa"
}

db.collection.updateOne(
{ 
  _id : ObjectId("1"),
  $or: [ 
      { info.first_name: { $ne: new_info.first_name }},
      { info.last_name: { $ne: new_info.last_name }},
      { info.phone: { $ne: new_info.phone }},
  ]
},
{
  $set: {
      info.first_name: new_info.first_name,
      info.last_name: new_info.last_name,
      info.phone: new_info.phone,
  }
}
)
```

You'd likely have to modify the above to only check for the other fields if they're present in the `req.body`. I'm also not certain if querying the nested documents like that is exactly right. However, I hope that gives you the general idea.

All credit goes to [Prasad_Saya](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/u/Prasad_Saya), who shared this exact approach on this [MongoDB forum post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/update-document-only-if-new-data-differs-from-current-data/139827)